# ¿Cómo traducir "shoulder days" en español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, español-neutral, tiempo, inglés

En el mundo de los hoteles hay un término en inglés "shoulder day" para nombrar los días inmediatamente antes o después de un día de alta demanda o mucha ocupación.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a traducir "shoulder day" en español?

Comment: Bajó el nivel de ocupación. La ocupación hotelera descendió los días x/para/en x fecha | Hubo días «flojos», una semana «floja» o estuvo «flojo» esos días, fue una temporada «lenta».  «Parejita» (informal)

Answer (score 1):

### Fechas Pico

> En ocasiones, un hotel puede generar ingresos adicionales al vender habitaciones en fechas pico; estas son básicamente fechas que están muy cerca de otras fechas de alta demanda.

<sub>*Fuente: [xotels.com](https://www.xotels.com/es/glosario/pico-eng-shoulder-dates)*</sub>

### Temporada hombro

Está claro que no hay una traducción al español estandarizada, esta es otra alternativa utilizada por [este operador turístico](https://es.ticotourandtravel.com/5396-shoulder-season-great-value-for-tourists).

### Período de hombro

> Nuestros períodos son:
>
> • Periodo pico (julio, agosto)
>
> • Período de hombro (junio, septiembre)

Según [este operador turístico](https://sail-ingreece.es/navegar-en-cruceros-por-grecia/ionian-cruceros/#tab-3).

Comment: No sé como se dice pero fechas pico no me parece bien. fechas pico sería peak dates.

Comment: Ciertamente, esa traducción de xotels se contradice a sí misma.

Answer (score 1):

https://sites.google.com/site/revenueyieldmanagement/pagina-4

Por acá se diría "flojo" como tal, como dice aquí:

> - **Shoulder period**: **Período flojo** (periodo de tiempo entre una temporada de alta ocupación y una temporada de baja ocupación en lo cual el hotel ofrece tarifas promocionales)

> - Advance-reservation discount: **Descuento** dado a grupos que hacen su **reservación con mucha anticipación**.

> - Rate cutting: **Reducción de tarifa**, (descuentos en tarifas de habitación para atraer clientes)

> - Promotional rate: Tarifa de habitación **promocional**, cualquier tarifa que no sea la tarifa rack, vea rack rate y rate cutting y shoulder period y standby rate.

> - Day rate: Una **tarifa reducida** para el uso de una habitación por el huésped durante el día después de la hora de salida, normalmente 17.00 horas, vea part-day rate y use rate.

> - Group pickup: Cantidad de habitaciones reservadas y **garantizadas** para un grupo.

> - Net pickup: La cantidad de reservaciones hechas **para una sola fecha** en el futuro.

> - Option date: Fecha tentativa, (fecha ofrecida a un grupo tentativamente en caso de que la agencia de viaje no esta seguro de tomar esta fecha como la de llegada, el hotel **impone una fecha limite hasta que la agencia puede confirmar**)

> - Block booking: Una cierta cantidad de habitaciones **reservadas para un grupo en específico** y asignada por recepción en el día de llegada.

Answer (score 0):

---

Que tal?

Comprendiendo el concepto "Shoulder Day";

- Básicamente los Shoulder Dates, son fechas en el calendario que están muy cerca de otras fechas de gran demanda. Por ejemplo, una pareja tiene reserva para el viernes y el sábado en un hotel elegido de la costa de Málaga en el mes de Agosto (mes que se estima es de gran demanda), sin embargo, una vez allí deciden extender su estancia una noche más, al Domingo.
  Este tipo de reserva sería, "**shoulder day**".

Para comprender el término "shoulder-day", hay que imaginar la distancia que existe entre nuestros hombros, es una distancia muy corta, en este sentido como la nueva reserva hecha por la pareja de Málaga es inmediatamente realizada después de las otras fechas de reserva previa que habían llevado a cabo anteriormente y que en principio no tenían proyectado, se utiliza el término "hombro/shoulder" para indicar ese espacio corto de proximidad, en este caso pegando al día ó días siguientes.

- De forma más coloquial "shoulder-dates" se utiliza también en hostelería simplemente para el día de antes y después del pico de temporada.

En *el idioma Español*, no tenemos un término en concreto que comprima exactamente el concepto. Por lo que entiendo, existen otros términos generales para indicar una gran demanda y afluencia de personas como *días calientes*, *días rojos*, *fechas pico*, *fechas fuera de temporada*, *periodo de menos actividad*..., pero no recogen del todo el planteamiento sugerido.

Si lo que se desea es dar una especie de explicación a alguien que desconoce el término shoulder-day probaría con;

- Reserva Prolongada.
- Extensión de reserva.
- Extensión de la reserva de salida en fechas de alta demanda.
- Extensión del check-out (salida)  en fechas de gran demanda.
- Referentes a las reservas del día anterior y posterior al pico de temporada.

P.D. Normalmente el símil más habitual que se le dado ha sido el de "*fechas de pico*", pero realmente para mi, eso se refiere a otra cosa, utilizando de forma generalizada el de reserva prologada ó extendida.

Espero que te haya ayudado. Saludos. *Diego M*.

Comment: Como suena: Dias/fechas de demanda extendida ?!

Comment: Día de Demanda Extendida ó DDE, esta bien!